# sql update not changing data in DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made a simple update query using PDO in PHP :

```
$pdos = connect_db(); 
$pdos->beginTransaction();
try {
    $query = "UPDATE `myo`.`question` SET `intitule` = 'Question azeerrr' WHERE `question`.`id` = 1"; 
    $pdo = $pdos->prepare($query);
    $pdo->execute();
    return $pdo->rowCount();
catch (Exception $e) { print_r ($e); exit (); }
```

Which doesnt seem to work (the data is not changed in the database) even though i get no error message and even receive "1" from rowCount() meaning the update was successful.

And also, if i copy and paste this query in PHPmyadmin and run it, it works and the row is modified,

Could it be something about rights to execute an UPDATE from my website and not beeing the same as when you are logged into PHPmyadmin?

EDIT : 
`FIXED : thanks for you help : PDO::commit(); was needed to close my PDO::beginTransaction();`

Comment: Is your data different from what is was before you did the update? If nothing changed, the rowCount could still return 0 as it only returns changed rows.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

`Example #1 Return the number of deleted rows

PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you begin a transaction with `$pdos->beginTransaction();` I'm pretty sure that you need commit it using `$pdos->commit();`

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) for more information.

Comment: thank you, indeed commit() on the PDO object was needed. 

It was stupid from me. I have actually other older functions with INSERT that also require commit(), but i realize now they're all set up with rollback() as my site is not live yet, hence i did not realize that commit() was needed since i started my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO's transaction, you must commit your changes to apply the modifications in your database.

See [PDO::commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you update a record with new values or with existing values,  MySql always returns 1 in both the cases....